# Why can't I assign an empty code block to a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm using V8 (via Chrome) to test this. In Javascript, a code block evaluates to whatever the last value in the code block evaluates to. I wanted to see **what would happen if I assigned a variable to an empty code block.**

```
// example of code block evaluating to last value in the block
> {1;2;3};
3

// This won't work, it returns an empty object,
// not an empty code block.
> var emptyBlock = {};
> emptyBlock;
Object object
```

Eventually, I figured out how to specify that I want an empty code block, not an empty object.

```
> {;}
undefined

> {;;}
undefined

> {;;;;;}
undefined
```

Okay, beautiful, so an empty code block resolves to `undefined`. Right?

### Not exactly!

```
> var emptyBlock = {;}
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'
```

?! Now it is unclear whether the empty code block actually returns `undefined`, or something else entirely is at play. If it merely did evaluate to `undefined`, we would expect the above assignment to work.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: An "empty code block" is simply not a value that can be assigned. You can make a *function* of course.

Comment: What is the actual goal???

Comment: @Pointy I was thinking that since codeblocks evaluate to whatever the last expression in the codeblock evaluates to, and an empty codeblock appears to evaluate to undefined (which itself seems intuitive), it should be able to be stored that way in a variable

Comment: @epascarello Fun and curiosity

Comment: I think what you see is just what the console does, it returns the last thing it ran.... there is really no return from a block.

Comment: You're confusing the operation of the *console* with how JavaScript code actually works. A `{` starts an object literal when an expression is expected, and it starts a block of code when it's the first token in a statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Eventually, I figured out how to specify that I want an empty code block, not an empty object.

This is largely determined by what is **before** the `{`, not after it.

Since you have an `=` before it, you are in a context where `{` is the start of an object literal. A `;` is not allowed where a property name is expected, so the code errors.

You can't assign blocks. They aren't values, they are parts of the code structure.

> Both of these seem demonstrably false. var codeBlockValue = {1;2;3}; for example works perfectly fine, and sets codeBlockValue to 3

No, it doesn't:

```js
var codeBlockValue = {1;2;3};
```

Comment: You say that the presence of `=` means that it will be interpreted as an object literal. Then say that you can't assign blocks. Both of these seem demonstrably false. `var codeBlockValue = {1;2;3};` for example works perfectly fine, and sets `codeBlockValue` to `3`.

Comment: @seisvelas but that code is a syntax error; it does not set the variable to anything.

Comment: Dude! I completely missed that!! I could have sworn I had tried that. Woah, thanks guys!